# Compare different length char arrays in c++ without string library

Tags: c++

I have 2 char arrays, one with length 50, other whose length varies from 1...50. I need to compare these.

The problem is, that the array containing 50 chars, usually contains less chars, but when comparing, it also takes them into account. So if I have 2 array, whose value is `U2`, length of first will be 50, the second - 2.

So, how do I check this, without using the standard string library? I must not use the string library, that is a prerequisite.

Comment: Is the reason you can't use the standard library because this is for homework?

Comment: I think to get a meaningful answer you're going to have to tell us what you mean by: "the array containing 50 chars, usually contains less chars". It either contains 50 chars or it contains fewer, but the number can't be both 50 and fewer than 50 at the same time. Do you mean an array of 50 chars, but fewer are meaningful? If so, what tells how many are meaningful? Is it a string (terminated with a zero-byte)? What about the other?

Comment: Yes, this is for a homework. However, this is NOT the whole homework. The whole homework requires me to create quite a complex searchable structure, using lists and queues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you aren’t allowed to use the standard library functionality then your first task is to re-program the required functionality. In your example, this would be `strcmp`.

Programming this function isn’t difficult – searching online should find you several possible implementations.

Roughly:

- Start walking through both strings in a loop until encountering a null char in either string.
- If both terminate in a null char at the same time, they are equal; otherwise the longer string is greater.
- Inside the loop, compare each individual character.

  - If the characters are equal, continue;
  - Otherwise, return.

Answer (score 2):

If the strings have different sizes, I think you are better with `strncmp()`:

```
int strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n);
```

From the *man* pages:

> It returns an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if s1 is found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2.

There's a custom implementation [here](http://uthcode.googlecode.com/svn-history/r501/trunk/cprogs/mystrncmp.c) to get you started.